# Moving Rigidbody using player input

Tags: unity-game-engine

Im trying to move an object in a 3d world using a controller, but think I am missing something cus it just clips away as soon as I give any input:

```c#
private void Update()
{
    float h = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
    float v = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

    Vector3 movement = new Vector3(h, 0, v).normalized * Time.deltaTime * speed;
    if(h != 0 || v != 0)
        _rigidBody.MovePosition(movement);
}
```

Works fine using `_rigidbody.velocity`, but as I understand it that should be avoided for these types of things.

Comment: you should only use this and all Physics related stuff only in [`FixedUpdate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.FixedUpdate.html) instead of `Update`. Also see [Rigidbody.MovePosition](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MovePosition.html). We don't know your `speed` value but maybe it is simply to big?

Comment: there's no reason you can't use rigidybody.velocity. it will just give unrealistic physics. but if you don't care about then go for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Rigidbody.MovePosition](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MovePosition.html) sets the position of the rigidbody with interpolation. It looks like you want to offset the position by `movement`, so you should probably set the velocity. If you do still want to use `MovePosition`, you should do `_rigidBody.MovePosition(transform.position + movement);`.

Answer (score 0):

> "using a controller"

Do you mean [Character Controller](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CharacterController.Move.html) Component? You have 2 options and they are both well explained in Unity Documentation.
Second is by [Rigidbody](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.html) Component.

Comment: I'm pretty sure they mean a gamepad, like an xbox controller.

Comment: @Julxzs aa.. I see, thank you for clarifying it, I call that Joystick. If that is the case, he can use one from Unity in Standard Assets. Works fine.